# Latex pgfplots loglogaxis scaling

Tags: latex, scale, axis

I have loglog axis in Latex and i want to change scaling of the y-Axis like this: y-Axis should be signed with: 5*10e1, 10e2, 2*10e2 But this numbers should be shown in integer like: 50, 100, 200. The gird of the diagramm should be stay the same.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[paperwidth=18cm, paperheight=12cm]{geometry}

%Digrammzeug
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty} % um die Seitenzahl zu endfernen
\newgeometry{left=0.1cm, right=0.1cm, top=0.1cm, bottom=0.1cm}


\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{loglogaxis}[
   axis x line=bottom,
   axis y line=left,
   ymax = 2.1*10^2,
   xlabel=N (log),
  ylabel=$ \mathrm{S_a} $ in MPa (log),
  every axis x label/.style={
     at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
     anchor=west,
  },
  every axis y label/.style={
     at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
     anchor=south,
  },
  ytick={10, 100},  
  scale=1.6,
  grid=both,
  tick align=outside,
  tickpos=left,
  ]

  %Lasth 1
  \node at (axis cs: 10^5.25,10^2.193) {Lasthorizont I};

  %Lasth 2
  \node at (axis cs: 10^6.2,10^1.955) {Lasthorizont II};

  %Lasth 1 - 2 Gerade
  \addplot[black, mark=square*] coordinates { (50966, 155.74) (477468, 90.16)};

  %Lasth 2 - N_D Gerade
  \addplot[black,no marks] coordinates { (477468, 90.16) (2.5*10^6, 60.16677272)};

  %Dauerfestigkeit
  \addplot[black, mark=square*, mark indices={1}] coordinates { (2.5*10^6, 60.16677272) (10^7, 60.16677272)};
  \addplot[black, dotted, no marks] coordinates { (2.5*10^6, 60.16677272) (10^7.3, 60.16677272) };  
  \addplot[black, dashed] coordinates { (10^4, 60.16677272) (2.5*10^6, 60.16677272) };

  %Beschriftung
  \addplot[dashed] coordinates { (2.5*10^6, 60.16677272) (2.5*10^6, 10^1.7)};
  \node at (axis cs: 10^5.4,10^1.85) {Zeitfestigkeit};
  \node at (axis cs: 10^5.4,10^1.74) {Dauerfestigkeit};
  \node at (axis cs: 10^6.85,10^1.73) {$ N_D=2,5\cdot10^6 $};
  \node at (axis cs: 10^4.4,10^1.Cool {$ S_{aD} \approx $ 60.17};

  %Lasthorizont III
  \addplot[black, thick, mark=x] coordinates {(180000, 117.49)};
  \node at (axis cs: 10^5.8, 10^2.07) {Lasthorizont III};

  \end{loglogaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this question has been asked long ago, and belongs on [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), but for those who are looking for a solution and find this question without an answer; I've found a working solution which I will share below.
I found the answer to your question in @Jake's [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139084/79580) and [two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107804/79580) answers.

---

What you're looking for (I think) is a combination of the `axis` environment with `xmode=log` and `ymode=log`. In order to get the axis labeled you combine it with `log ticks with fixed point`. This is a default pgf option which will modify both axis.

Since you're asking for only specific y-axis ticks I use this for the working example below using a new definition of a `pgfplotsset`. By the way, I commented the line with `.Cool` since I'm not familiar with this and it causes problems with me, feel free to un-comment it.

```
   \begin{tikzpicture}

   \pgfplotsset{
  log x ticks with fixed point/.style={
      xticklabel={
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
        \pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}%
        \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed relative, precision=3]{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
      }
  },
  log y ticks with fixed point/.style={
      yticklabel={
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
        \pgfmathparse{exp(\tick)}%
        \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed relative, precision=3]{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
      }
  }
}

   \begin{axis}
   [xmode=log,
   ymode=log,
   log x ticks with fixed point,
   axis x line=bottom,
   axis y line=left,
   ymax = 2.1*10^2,
   xlabel=N (log),
  ylabel=$ \mathrm{S_a} $ in MPa (log),
  every axis x label/.style={
     at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
     anchor=west,
  },
  every axis y label/.style={
     at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
     anchor=south,
  },
  ytick={10, 100},  
  scale=1.6,
  grid=both,
  tick align=outside,
  tickpos=left,
  ]

  %Lasth 1
  \node at (axis cs: 10^5.25,10^2.193) {Lasthorizont I};

  %Lasth 2
  \node at (axis cs: 10^6.2,10^1.955) {Lasthorizont II};

  %Lasth 1 - 2 Gerade
  \addplot[black, mark=square*] coordinates { (50966, 155.74) (477468, 90.16)};

  %Lasth 2 - N_D Gerade
  \addplot[black,no marks] coordinates { (477468, 90.16) (2.5*10^6, 60.16677272)};

  %Dauerfestigkeit
  \addplot[black, mark=square*, mark indices={1}] coordinates { (2.5*10^6, 60.16677272) (10^7, 60.16677272)};
  \addplot[black, dotted, no marks] coordinates { (2.5*10^6, 60.16677272) (10^7.3, 60.16677272) };  
  \addplot[black, dashed] coordinates { (10^4, 60.16677272) (2.5*10^6, 60.16677272) };

  %Beschriftung
  \addplot[dashed] coordinates { (2.5*10^6, 60.16677272) (2.5*10^6, 10^1.7)};
  \node at (axis cs: 10^5.4,10^1.85) {Zeitfestigkeit};
  \node at (axis cs: 10^5.4,10^1.74) {Dauerfestigkeit};
  \node at (axis cs: 10^6.85,10^1.73) {$ N_D=2,5\cdot10^6 $};
  %\node at (axis cs: 10^4.4,10^1.Cool {$ S_{aD} \approx $ 60.17};

  %Lasthorizont III
  \addplot[black, thick, mark=x] coordinates {(180000, 117.49)};
  \node at (axis cs: 10^5.8, 10^2.07) {Lasthorizont III};

  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

This provides the following figure:

[image: Which provides the following]